# Format integer to formatted date in an SQLite select statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database within my Android application, which stores dates as integers. These integers are derived from a call to `Java.util.Date.getTime();`. I am trying to run a raw query of my database to get a Cursor to pass to a CursorAdapter and display in a ListView, but the date is stored as an integer as returned by `getTime()`.

To keep my program simple, I would like to avoid using a SimpleArrayAdapter, and stick with the CursorAdapter.

Is it somehow possible to format the integer within the date column as `mm-dd-yyyy` so that the column of the table, that the cursor is pointing to, contains properly formatted values rather than the integer that was returned by `Java.util.Date.getTime();` when I added the item to the database?

Comment: Why not use the calendar methods instead, then you can format the date however you please http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: I didn't know whether to select Matthew Flaschen's or Ezra's answer as best, as they are both through and correct. Thank you both for the assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime("%m-%d-%Y", date_col, 'unixepoch') AS date_col
```

Your code will work if it expects a result set column in that format called date_col.

EDIT: One thing you need to watch out for is that [getTime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) uses milliseconds since 1970, while standard UNIX time (including SQLite) uses seconds.

Comment: Ok, so my idea was to store the value into the database as Date.getTime()/1000, however this date is coming back from strftime as <correct month>, <correct date>, <correct year> + 1900. For example, something stored with new Date().getTime()/1000 (today) displays as 03-12-3911 instead of 03-12-2011, is my /1000 logic flawed somehow?

Comment: @segfault, probably you're just creating the `Date` object wrong.  You need to pass into [the constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) (or set) the "the year minus 1900."

Answer (score 5):

The `Java.util.Date.getTime();` method is returning an integer that represents the "[unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)".

The simplest way to read this number as a date is by storing it as-is, and reading it using the following Sqlite query:

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%d-%Y', 1092941466, 'unixepoch');
```

which returns:

```
08-19-2004
```

If you need another format, you can use the [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function to format is as you like, or any of the other date formats and functions available.

You'll have to, as Matthew Flaschen points out in a commend below, divide the date by 1000 before you are able to use them in this way.  "Real" unix times are measured in seconds since the epoch, and `Java.util.Date.getTime();` returns *milliseconds* since epoch.

Comment: I don't understand what "1092941466" is in your above select statement. Wouldn't I want this to be the name of the column containing the date?

Comment: Yes.  It's nothing in particular; just some unix-style date, needed to test the example on my system.  

In your query, you want to substitute it for the appropriate column.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, will the column of formatted dates have the same name as the column that the date is stored in, or some other name? Right now, it seems that my app is crashing when trying to display this information because a column with the name of my date column does not exist on the table of the cursor returned by rawQeury.

Comment: The answer by @Matthew Flaschen cleared that issue up. Thanks a lot for the help. I am now having the issue where strft is always returning 01-01-1970 even though the dates in the database differ. (As an example, one is 61258046400000.)

Comment: `getTime` is not quite identical to UNIX time, since it uses milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite uses static rigid typing. With static typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the particular column in which the value is stored.

Any value stored in the SQLite database has one of the following storage class:

1. NULL
2. INTEGER
3. REAL
4. TEXT
5. BLOB

so I am not sure what you meant by `but the date is stored as a long, unhelpful integer.`

For more details please refer to *[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)*. For further information on storing date/time in SQLite please refer to *[SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)*.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had dates coming out of Excel around 45000, which is days since Jan 1970.
Here's what worked for me in SQLite:

```
SELECT
strftime('%m-%d-%Y', ("Start Date"-25569)*86400, 'unixepoch') AS WeekStartDate,
strftime('%m-%d-%Y', ("End Date"-25569)*86400, 'unixepoch') AS WeekEndDate
FROM SalesByWeek
```