# How to change date format in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, date-format

How do I change the format of a date in %d/%m/%Y or any other from this string 10/09/2016 in sqlite?

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', '09-10-2016'),t_date from party_trans
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Currently your question is rather broad. What's the actual error you get? Which language are you using? Which date format are you using for sqlite? Depending on these, it's likely that this question also has [been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287064/format-integer-to-formatted-date-in-an-sqlite-select-statement) [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661177/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-date-format-in-sqlite-selected-vaues) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166809/sqlite-selecting-date-with-different-date-format). Did you do any searching yourself?

Comment: please read properly, i mentioned every thing

Comment: yes it is very true that this question asked many times but this is little change

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types/18688/date-time-types)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this query

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y',datetime(substr(t_date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(t_date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(t_date, 1, 2))) from party_trans;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to store date as time stamp instead of string. Timestamp gives you more flexibility and accuracy than date. Convert your date into millisecond (timestamp) format and store it into your database as INTEGER type.

Or try this:

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', '2016-10-09');
```

Comment: thank you , but  my old data store with ('%d/%m/%Y', '09-10-2016') format!

Answer (score 0):

Store date into INTEGER type in database.

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date) from table
```